# Stripe Payment Intent Issue

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I have integrated **Stripe API** with my application. Previously the **capture_method** was **manual** and the payment flow was working as expected. But recently I have changed the **capture_method** to **automatic** and after that I am receiving PaymentIntent error with status code 400.

The error is showing as:

```
"code": "payment_intent_unexpected_state",
"message": "This PaymentIntent could not be captured because it has already been captured."
```

The payment I am accepting is card payment with 3D security enabled.

Could you please let me know what is the issue here and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

The `capture_method` parameter lets you decide whether you want Stripe to capture the funds immediately (value `automatic`) or if you want them to "place a hold" on the funds so that you decide later whether to capture them or release them (value `manual`).

If you switch to `capture_method: 'automatic'` then the PaymentIntent will end up with `status: 'succeeded'` after a successful confirmation. At that point the funds on the card are already captured and will be pending in your account balance.

If you try to call the Capture PaymentIntent [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/capture) in that situation you will get the error you mentioned since the funds have already been captured. You need to change your code to never call that API anymore if the PaymentIntent is already captured.